# How can I return a component from Application to module?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2, android-module

Trying to understand the following [example](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/dagger-multi-module#implementation_with_dagger_subcomponents) and do something similar.

In my application there is a module, in which I want to use Dagger.
To do this I need an Application class in which I initialize and store `AppComponent`

Judging from the documentation I need to create an interface with a component from my module:

```
interface PasscodeSetupComponentProvider {
    fun providePasscodeSetupComponent(): PasscodeComponent
}
```

Then I will implement this interface for my Application class:

```
open class FenturyApplication : PasscodeSetupComponentProvider {

    lateinit var appComponent: AppComponent

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .appModule(AppModule(applicationContext))
            .build()
    }

    override fun providePasscodeSetupComponent(): PasscodeComponent {
        return appComponent.passcodeComponent
    }
}
```

But judging by the example from the documentation I don't understand what should be in my interface `Appcomponent` namely `passcodeComponent`.

In the example, it looks like this:

```
class MyApplication: Application(), LoginComponentProvider {
  // Reference to the application graph that is used across the whole app
  val appComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.create()

  override fun provideLoginComponent(): LoginComponent {
    return appComponent.loginComponent().create()
  }
}
```

I added the following code to my AppComponent:

```
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class])
@Singleton
interface AppComponent {
    val applicationContext: Context
    fun passcodeComponent(): PasscodeComponent
}
```

And if I understood correctly, then in the fragment that is in my module, I can write the following:

```
lateinit var passcodeComponent: PasscodeComponent

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val context = activity?.applicationContext ?: return
    passcodeComponent = (context as PasscodeSetupComponentProvider).providePasscodeSetupComponent()
    passcodeComponent.inject(this)
```

After that I hope I can use dagger in my module.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a crucial part of how AppComponent is written. You can read the complete code in [this](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/dagger-android#dagger-subcomponents) link.

Please note how Google is declaring the `LoginComponent` (as Subcomponent) and how do they declare it inside AppComponent in order do return a new instance of LoginComponent.

AppComponent (copied from the link I posted)

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [NetworkModule::class, SubcomponentsModule::class])
interface ApplicationComponent {
// This function exposes the LoginComponent Factory out of the graph so consumers
// can use it to obtain new instances of LoginComponent
fun loginComponent(): LoginComponent.Factory
}
```

And the code for LoginComponent

```
@Subcomponent
interface LoginComponent {

    // Factory that is used to create instances of this subcomponent
    @Subcomponent.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(): LoginComponent
    }

    fun inject(loginActivity: LoginActivity)
}
```